# Creating array from range of numbers

Tags: java

I need to create an array of doubles given a max and min and interval. So array will look something like {2.9, 4.9, 6.9,... etc}

I am getting an array of zeros.

```
public class FoolinAround {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double min = 2.9;
        double max = 20.6;
        double gap = 2.0;
        double count = (max - min) / gap + 2; // as will need first and last
                                                // element also

        double array[] = new double[(int) count];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            double i = array[j];
            min = min + gap;

        }
        for (double k : array) {
            System.out.print(array[(int) k] + ",");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No where do you have `array[j] = something`. How do you expect the array to be filled with anything if you don't assign anything to the array elements?

Comment: Note that this: `double i = array[j];` does nothing of use. It creates a local double variable, `i`, assigns 0 to this same local variable (since that's all the array holds), and then discards the same local variable.

Comment: I'm unclear what this array should hold when it's done. Please supply an example.

Comment: Please provide a full example, what happens at the end when it doesn't fit exactly? The `+ 2` is what's confusing me.

Comment: Thanks a million guys, that is really helpful. First time poster. Happy New Year!

Comment: Weston, the plus 2 is probably wrong - just trying to figure out a way to get length of array for declaring it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are missing the assignment to your array (`array[j] = something;`). It appears from your explantation that `array` is supposed to contain the results. If I understand the problem you are trying to solve, this looks like a solution.

```
public class FoolinAround {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double min = 2.9;
        double max = 20.6;
        double gap = 2.5;
        double count = (max - min) / gap + 2; // as will need first and last
                                                // element also

        double array[] = new double[(int) count];
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            array[j] = min + (j*gap);
        }
        for (double k : array) {
            System.out.print(array[(int) k] + ",");
        }

    }
}
```

I didn't verify that this calculation will give you the correct size for your array: `double count = (max - min) / gap + 2;`. I suggest that you verify this calculation. Since you are relying on truncation, rather than rounding, you may have an off-by-one error.

Comment: Thanks a million, sorry I am brand new to coding. Should have  spotted that. Just having a post Christmas mental block. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how

```
double[] array = DoubleStream.iterate(min, prev -> prev + gap)
                             .limit(count)
                             .toArray();
```

[Link to DoubleStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html)

Comment: Thank you Dummy, it is for a project so I can't use packages or libraries and have to use basic java but I really appreciate your response.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Btw, when you ask a question, don't forget to list your requirements so people who help will know to give you a better answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I found was with the assignment and the for-each loop. Here is how you can do it:

```
    double min = 2.9;
    double max = 20.6;
    double gap = 2.0;
    double count = (max - min) / gap + 2.0;

    System.out.println(count);
    double array[] = new double[(int) count];
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

        // double i = array[j]; /*Not sure why this assignment is used
        // here?*/
        array[j] = min;
        min += gap;

    }

    for (double k : array) {
        System.out.print(k + "\n"); // Here k is the double value from the
                                    // array. array[(int)k] will give you
                                    // element of array indexed at the
                                    // element of array.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Nimit, this was very helpful!